# My warmup request handler is being called several times when running the app from the locale dev setup

Tags: python, google-app-engine, localhost, warm-up

I have a warmup request in my Google App Engine project. However, the handler is called multiple times when testing on the local dev server

It is configured properly in the app.yaml file:

```
- url: /_ah/warmup
  script: main.app
  login: admin

inbound_services:
  - warmup
```

and is doing it's job...I just can't workout why it is being called multiple times. Is this something to do with the local dev setup or somethign I am doing wrong.

Here is the main.py minus the imports

```
class WarmUpRequestsHandler(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    """
    Warmup requests pre gae instance loading
    """

    def get(self):
        from google.appengine.api import memcache
        from product.lib.lib import ProductCaches

        logging.info('warmup request handler')

        kwargs = {
            'klass': TheLatest(),
            'products_qry': 'EMA',
            'product_entity': 'ema_latest',
            'memcache_key': 'ema-latest',
        }

        entity = ProductCaches(**kwargs)
        entity.get_and_set()
        self.response.headers['Content-Type'] = 'text/plain'
        self.response.write('Warmup successful')


webapp2_config = config.config

app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([("/_ah/warmup", WarmUpRequestsHandler)],debug = os.environ['SERVER_SOFTWARE'].startswith('Dev'), config=webapp2_config)
# Import All Routes

adminroutes.add_routes(app)
authroutes.add_routes(app)
emailroutes.add_routes(app)
hotroutes.add_routes(app)
mediaroutes.add_routes(app)
messageroutes.add_routes(app)
paymentroutes.add_routes(app)
productroutes.add_routes(app)
searchroutes.add_routes(app)
storeroutes.add_routes(app)
routes.add_routes(app)
```